# How to adjust T distribution for calculating confidence interval of bounded mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, t-distribution

Suppose I have a small sample of $n$ positive numbers. Since the sample is small I assume they are coming from a Student's T distribution. By knowing the degrees of freedom $d_f=n-1$ and the desired risk of error $\alpha$, I can compute the t-value $t$. With $\sigma$ as the estimated standard deviation and $\mu$ as the mean I can then compute a confidence interval $\mu \pm t \sigma /\sqrt{n}$.

It is possible that the left side of the interval is negative. But if the data is positive by nature (say it's the weight of robin eggs), I suppose there must be some good alternative to the T distribution? Even if the calculated interval is positive, there must be a better confidence interval that adjusts for the known lower bound of the estimated variable.

My question is: What it the best option for a small sample mean confidence interval when variable is positive by nature?

Bonus question: Is it even so that the right side of the confidence interval should be higher when the variance in the data can not come from the left tail of the distribution, if you see what I mean?

Comment: This question is unanswerable because it's predicated on several incorrect assumptions, beginning with assuming all small samples come from a Student $t$ distribution.  Do you have a particular problem we can address or are you trying to pose a general question?  If it's the latter, then the basis for this distributional assumption would be the place to start.

Comment: The best option is to convert the data into measurement system that has a better chance of being correct.  Certainly for robin eggs negative weights are not allowed such that the data are likely more normal as $\ln(W)$, i.e., log-normal transformed. Maybe put in some data if you want a better answer.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for replying. The particular problem at hand is the weight of robin eggs. Since sample size is less than 30, I was recommended to use T distribution instead of normal distribution. With a very small sample and high confidence level, such as 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 4.2 grams and 99 % confidence, the interval covers zero. Maybe, from a purist point of view, the correct answer is that the sample is too small - period?

Comment: @Carl, thanks. Taking the logarithm is a smart trick. Without going via log/exp I get a 99% confidence interval of $[-0.6, 5.8]$ for the samples [1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 4.2]. Going the log route, I get $[0.8, 6.5]$ instead - which intuitively feels more correct to me.

Comment: I would view the negative lower limit as a feature rather than an annoyance to be eradicated or papered over: it indicates that looking for a good estimate from a highly dispersed set of just four values with 99% confidence is asking for too much.  Also, since your stated objective is to estimate the mean, using logarithms won't do that: that will only provide you a confidence interval for the geometric mean.

Comment: @whuber  Organisms are in many ways fractal structures that obey power laws with scale independence. It is often a bigger mistake to assume normality and linear equations for such structures than log-normality and power functions. Do you really expect egg weight to ever be negative? The allometry of egg construction from power laws would seem more natural  https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-14552-0.

Comment: @Carl Nobody is assuming normality of egg weights.  I agree that certain assumptions suggest an analysis based on logarithms (or, perhaps better, cube roots) of weights could be useful, but have warned the OP that confidence intervals for nonlinearly transformed weights will not be the same, nor will they mean the same thing, as CIs for the weights themselves.

Comment: @whuber True enough, and I in turn am warning that expected values in statistical parlance are unrelated to any sense of anticipation in a larger sense, in particular for income, wealth, or body size.